# What does Stack Overflow use for the inbox and user popup?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tooltips, popups, jquery

When you click on Stack Exchange or the down arrow next to your name, a popup comes up.  Is this a jQuery plugin that does this? One of the tooltip plugins?

I assume it's not a dialog plugin, but I can't seem to find one that matches the formatting and behavior.

What does Stack Overflow use for this?

Comment: It's a custom development. You will probably not find a plugin that matches exactly the way it works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a plugin. It's just a bit of jQuery code that creates the HTML for the box, positions it on the page, and then issues an asynchronous request to pull the current data (hot questions, inbox messages, recent votes, etc.) in from the server.

You can [view the source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js) if you're curious about the implementation. Look for the bit that starts with `var genuwine=function(){`...

Comment: Just curious, what's "genuwine"? :)